# F#: How to "await" a function in a handler so that exception still bubble up to the handler?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, f#, async-await

I want to offload the handler used for a subscription for RabbitMQ with EasyNetQ, in C# I get what I want cause the handler itself is tagged as `async` and hence inside I can then await the offloading, in other words:

```cs
var subscription = bus.PubSub.Subscribe<Message>("subscriptionId", async message =>
{
    // Await Offloading
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // If it throws something here, it still bubble up to the handler
    });
});
```

However, in F# I am completely puzzled, does the C# code can be properly translated to F#?

I started to draft something, but this is clearly not the solution

```ml
let handle (message: Message) = async{
    printfn "%A" message
}

let subscription = bus.PubSub.Subscribe<Message>("subscriptionId", fun message ->
    handle message
    |> Async.Start
    )
```

This F# snippet does not properly address my question, it's two-folded:

- `handle` is not awaited
- exceptions that can occur in `handle` do not bubble up to the `fun` handler

Another improper way to tackle the problem is:

```ml
let handle (message: Message) = async{
    printfn "%A" message
}

let subscription = bus.PubSub.Subscribe<Message>("subscriptionId", fun message ->
    handle message
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
    )
```

But although this is awaited (unlike the snippet above), this one runs on the same thread and does not offload the work onto a threadpool thread.

Comment: Do you have some F# code that you have tried? That would help us know if you are using C#-style Tasks or F#-style async computations.

Comment: @WallaceKelly I updated my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A close approximation of what you're looking for would be something like this:

```
bus.PubSub.SubscribeAsync<Message>("subscriptionId", fun message ->
        async {
            do! handle message
        }
        |> Async.StartAsTask :> Task)
```

`async-await` constructs in C# only provide syntax sugar for composing `Tasks` - all the `.***Async` methods that are now ubiquitous in .NET apis are entirely usable from F#, though sometimes the necessary plumbing code can get unwieldy. The situation there [might be improving](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/pull/6811) in the future though.

Comment: I am still relatively new to F#, although your snippet answers my question, I am not too sure to get why the cast `:>` to `Task` is required considering that `Async.StartAsTask` is taking `Async<'T>` to return a `Task<'T>`

Comment: I supposed cause `Async.StartAsTask` return `Task<Unit>` hence the need to convert to `Task` to match the `SubscribeAsync` overload signature. 
Makes sense.

Comment: @EhouarnPerret: Yes, `Task` and `Task<'t>` are different types that are not interchangeable (like the split between `Action` and `Func`, that's something brought about because 'void' has no value).